# jpa validating detached objects

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

i'm trying to validate a new bean object using the jpa validation.

I'm getting this error:

```
2012-09-24 11:19:55,584 WARN  [AbstractModel:32] The object is not persisted yet, this operation requires the object to already be persisted.
java.lang.Exception
        at org.oscarehr.common.model.AbstractModel.hashCode(AbstractModel.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintViolationImpl.hashCode(ConstraintViolationImpl.java:127)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:389)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:322)
        at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:120)
        at org.apache.jsp.billing.CA.ON.reports.billingONNewReport_jsp.saveSubmittedBills(billingONNewReport_jsp.java:383)
        at org.apache.jsp.billing.CA.ON.reports.billingONNewReport_jsp._jspService(billingONNewReport_jsp.java:796)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
        at org.apache.jsp.billing.CA.ON.billingONReport_jsp._jspService(billingONReport_jsp.java:109)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
....
```

I'm using:

```
hibernate-entitymanager 3.4.0.GA
hibernate-validator 4.1.0.Final
validation-api 1.0.0.GA
```

I'm calling my validation code like this:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
                Set<ConstraintViolation<BillingClaimHeader1>>  constraintViolations = validator.validate(newBill);
                MiscUtils.getLogger().info("num violations: " + constraintViolations.size());
```

Where `newBill` is a new instance of class `BillingClaimHeader1`.

Here's the class definition for `BillingClaimHeader1`:

```
public class BillingClaimHeader1 extends AbstractModel<Integer> implements Serializable
```

I'm pretty new to the whole JPA/validation thing, but I didn't realize that I had to persist an object BEFORE validating it...seems kind of counter-intuitive..

I appreciate any help!

cheers

Jarrett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

1. This message comes from `org.oscarehr.common.model.AbstractModel`, not JPA
2. It's a warning, not an error

Actually, you can safely ignore this message in your case.

`org.oscarehr.common.model.AbstractModel` uses entity identifier to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. This approach has one disadvantage when used with generated identifiers - it breaks the contract of `equals()` and `hashCode()` when you save an object, i.e. `hashCode()` of a transient object differs from `hashCode()` of the same object after you saved it.

To inform you about possible problems authors of `org.oscarehr.common.model.AbstractModel` decided to emit a warning when you call `hashCode()` on a transient object. However, in your case you can safely ignore this warning, because `hashCode()` is called internally by validation routines that operate on transient objects only (as far as I understand).

**See also:**

- [Equals and HashCode](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode)

Answer (score 0):

Your Entity are detach with `PersistenceContext`. You have to do`manage state` for that instance.